# Is there a specialized stacked widget layout in gtk?

Tags: layout, gtk3

I want to have two (or more) sets of widgets which are switched to each other in the same window.

Is there a specialized stacked widget layout in GTK?

If not, what is the shortest way to implement this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a widget for this: `GtkStack`, available in GTK 3.10 and later.

If you don't have GTK 3.10, you can do much the same thing (but without animations) by putting the widgets in a `GtkNotebook` and making the notebook tabs invisible.